# Difference between echo $(cal) and echo "$(cal)"

Tags: linux, shell, calendar, ubuntu-16.04, echo

I'm using `echo $(cal)` and `echo "$(cal)"`in Linux and it gives me different results as in the picture. The double quotes should not interfere with `$` in this case, so what gives the `echo "$(cal)"` that horizontal style comparing to `echo $(cal)`.

This is the result:

[image: Screenshot of output]

`echo "$(cal)"`

```
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
                   1  
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15  
16 17 18 19 20 21 22  
23 24 25 26 27 28 29  
30
```

`echo $(cal)`

```
June 2019 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two key differences:

1. The shell performs *word splitting* on the unquoted `$(cal)`.  This means, assuming a default value for `IFS`, that all strings of white space (including newlines) are replaced with a single blank.  This is the output from the unquoted command is on a single line.

   Here is a simpler example:

   ```
   $ s='line     1
   > line  2'
   $ echo "$s"
   line     1
   line  2
   $ echo $s
   line 1 line 2
   ```

   As you can see, in the second `echo`, the one without double quotes, all sequences of white space have been replaced by single blanks.  This is just what you saw when using `echo` without double-quotes with `echo $(cal)`.
2. The shell performs *pathname expansion* on the result of the word splitting.  This doesn't happen to make any difference in your example but, if your output included `?` or `*` or other glob-active characters, it could lead to some surprises.

   Here is a simple example of *pathname expansion*.  Let's start with a directory with three files:

   ```
   $ ls
   file1  file2  file3
   ```

   Now, let's define a string:
       $ s='file?'

   Now, see that `echo` with double-quotes returns our string but, without double-quotes, the string is expanded into file names:

   ```
   $ echo "$s"
   file?
   $ echo $s
   file1 file2 file3
   ```